# UIView tap recognizer not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Trying to make work tap recognition on a UIView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView_: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewInfo: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /* MapView inital values & dependencies */
    let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.78, -122.41)
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(initialLocation, zoom: 10)

    /* Set up MapView */
    mapView_.camera = camera
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView_.delegate = self

    var selfTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:")
    viewInfo.addGestureRecognizer(selfTap)
    viewInfo.userInteractionEnabled = true
    mapView_.insertSubview(viewInfo, aboveSubview: mapView_)
}
func viewTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void{
    NSLog("tapped")
}
```

It doesn't recognize the tap.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: can you post the whole code ? because if both answers are not working we need to see what is really wrong

Answer (score 2):

Problem "solved"

The problem occurred due to the viewInfo being a subView of googlemaps view. 
I couldn't delegate tap event to viewcontroller, so I assumed the event "tap" was being sending to mapview.

I took out the viewInfo from mapview and played a little with constraints to place where I wanted it. So the parent of viewInfo now is viewcontroller and the tap event is recognized without any problem.

I guess this is not the better solution as we need to be very careful when moving the subview in the storyboard to not let it becomes part of mapview, but for while I can't figure out how delegate the subview to viewcontroller.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `:` from `handleTap:` or you need to change your method to `handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)`

Comment: Tried both options, still not recognizing. TY

Answer (score 0):

use:

```js
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NSLog("tapped")
}
```

Comment: my code is : 
var selfTap: UITapGestureRecognizer =
            UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:"
selfTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
backGrayView.addGestureRecognizer(selfTap);
backGrayView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

func viewTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void{
     if recognizer.numberOfTouches() == 1{
          CODE HERE
     } 
}

Comment: Strange, still not working, copy and paste your code with small adaptation to my view. Is it possible to be a sub view over google map ? mapView_.insertSubview(viewInfo, aboveSubview: mapView_)

Comment: what about bring your view to the front?

Comment: it is already, I can't interact with map tapping over subview